# c# iText7 PDF AddNewPage fails

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I put here a piece of code in c # and iText7 PDF. I don't know why it doesn't print 3 sheets with 3 lines each, since I have a 'AddNewPage' in front of each group of 3 lines (only print one page with 9 lines). Can you help me. Thank you.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var writer = new PdfWriter(@"C:\PDFDir\TestPDF.pdf");
    var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    var document = new Document(pdf);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("");

    document.SetMargins(6, 0, 0, 18);   //T,R,B,L

    pdf.AddNewPage();                   //Page 1
    p = new Paragraph("Line 1 page 1");
    document.Add(p);
    p = new Paragraph("Line 2 page 1");
    document.Add(p);
    p = new Paragraph("Line 3 page 1");
    document.Add(p);

    pdf.AddNewPage();                    //Page 2 ?
    p = new Paragraph("Line 1 page 2");
    document.Add(p);
    p = new Paragraph("Line 2 page 2");
    document.Add(p);
    p = new Paragraph("Line 3 page 2");
    document.Add(p);

    pdf.AddNewPage();                    //Page 3 ?
    p = new Paragraph("Line 1 page 3");
    document.Add(p);
    p = new Paragraph("Line 2 page 3");
    document.Add(p);
    p = new Paragraph("Line 3 page 3");
    document.Add(p);

    document.Close();

} //End of button1_Click
```

Comment: To have a `Document` instance put the content added afterwards onto a new page, you have to tell that `Document` instance so, not the underlying `PdfDocument` instance, by using `document.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40860358/1729265).

Comment: I added the line 'document.Add (new AreaBreak (iText.Layout.Properties.AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));' replacing the previous 'pdf.AddNewPage();' and now it works correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you're mixing up your targets, you add each new `Paragraph` to the `Document`, but add your new pages to the `PdfDocument`. Try adding your breaks to the document.

```
var pdf = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(docPdf, new FileStream(<path>, FileMode.Create));
pdf.Open();
pdf.Add(new Paragraph("Line 1 page 1"));
pdf.NewPage();
pdf.Close();
```

Comment: The OP mentions iText 7 in his question text. Your code is for iText 5.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me. the one that has gone well has been the previous comment of mkl.