# iText7 PDF with multiple Page in Custom Size

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I have used iText5 in a Software for generating ID-Cards (Name, Barcode etc.).
It Produces a PDF-File with every ID-Card as a Page.

Now is iText5 not running anymore and I switched to 7. But the old Logic in new Syntax is producing not the same.

```
internal static string erzeugeAusweisdruck(List<int> schlüsselSammlung, String connectionString, string druck_id)
    {
        string rückgabe = "";

        try
        {
            // einmaligen Dateinamen erzeugen
            string dateiendungPdf = ".pdf";
            string stempel = DateTime.Now.Year + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month + "_" + DateTime.Now.Day + "_" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "_" + DateTime.Now.Second;
            string pdfDateinameKomplett = "AUSGABE/Ausweisdruck_" + stempel + dateiendungPdf;
            rückgabe = pdfDateinameKomplett;
            // Ausweisgrößen von Millimeter in Pixel umrechnen
            float ausweishöhe = 153;
            float ausweisbreite = 251;
            // Viereck für die Ausweisgröße
            iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle ausweisgröße = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, ausweisbreite, ausweishöhe);
            using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfDateinameKomplett))
            {
                using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer))
                {
                    using (Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, new iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize(ausweisgröße)))
                    {
                        PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfDoc.GetDocumentInfo();
                        info.SetTitle("Ausweisdruck");

                        // Ausweise generieren (schlüsselSammlung durchlaufen)
                        foreach (int schlüssel in schlüsselSammlung)
                        {
                            // Antrag generieren und prüfen ob Ausweis-Nummer existiert
                            ausweisantrag tempAntrag = new ausweisantrag(schlüssel.ToString(), connectionString);
                            string ausweisnummer = "";
                            // Person erzeugen
                            string personid = tempAntrag.personID;
                            // kein so komplexes Objekt nötig !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                            // person personObjekt = new person(tempAntrag.personID);
                            person personObjekt = person.erzeugePersonObjektNurNameUndGeburtsdatum(tempAntrag.personID, connectionString);
                            // Ausweisnummer = Verbandsnummer
                            ausweisnummer = person.holeVerbandsnummer(tempAntrag.personID, connectionString);
                            // AB HIER EINZELNE AUSWEISE bzw. SEITEN
                            // itext Barcode (Code 39)
                            // BARCODE ERZEUGEN
                            Barcode39 barcode39 = new Barcode39(pdfDoc);
                            barcode39.SetCode(ausweisnummer);
                            barcode39.SetBarHeight(25);
                            // GDI+
                            iText.Layout.Element.Image bcImage = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(barcode39.CreateFormXObject(pdfDoc));
                            barcode39 = null;
                            
                            // SCHRIFTEN
                            iText.Kernel.Colors.Color schwarz = ColorConstants.BLACK;
                            string schriftart = iText.IO.Font.Constants.StandardFonts.HELVETICA;
                            PdfFont schriftGrossFett = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(schriftart);
                            Style grossFett = new Style().SetFontSize(10).SetBold().SetFontColor(schwarz).SetFont(schriftGrossFett);
                            PdfFont schriftGrossDünn = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(schriftart);
                            Style grossDünn = new Style().SetFontSize(8).SetFontColor(schwarz).SetFont(schriftGrossDünn);
                            PdfFont schriftKlein = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(schriftart);
                            Style klein = new Style().SetFontSize(6).SetFont(schriftKlein).SetFontColor(schwarz);
                            // Name und Geburtsdatum in einer Zeile (Tabelle)
                            // Paragraph hat im gegensatz zu Paragraph die Option ALIGNMENT
                            Paragraph labelGeburtsdatum = new Paragraph(personObjekt.geburtsdatum.Value.ToShortDateString()).AddStyle(grossDünn);
                            labelGeburtsdatum.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
                            Paragraph labelMitgliedName = new Paragraph(personObjekt.vorname + " " + personObjekt.nachname).AddStyle(grossFett);
                            // LEADING ist Zeilenhöhe
                            labelMitgliedName.SetFixedLeading(8);
                            // Tabelle mit 2 Spalten (75% und 25% Breite)
                            Table tabelleNameGeburtsdatum = new Table(new float[] { 3, 1 });
                            tabelleNameGeburtsdatum.SetWidth(ausweisbreite);
                            //tabelleNameGeburtsdatum.LockedWidth = true;
                            tabelleNameGeburtsdatum.SetMargin(0);
                            Cell zelleName = new Cell();
                            zelleName.SetPaddingLeft(8);
                            zelleName.SetPaddingTop(65);
                            // JEDE ZELLE MUSS BORDER ENTFERNT WERDEN
                            Border keinRahmen = Border.NO_BORDER;
                            zelleName.SetBorder(keinRahmen);
                            zelleName.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
                            zelleName.Add(labelMitgliedName);
                            tabelleNameGeburtsdatum.AddCell(zelleName);
                            Cell zelleGeburtsdatum = new Cell();
                            zelleGeburtsdatum.SetPaddingTop(65);
                            zelleGeburtsdatum.SetPaddingRight(8);
                            zelleGeburtsdatum.SetBorder(keinRahmen);
                            zelleGeburtsdatum.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                            zelleGeburtsdatum.Add(labelGeburtsdatum);
                            tabelleNameGeburtsdatum.AddCell(zelleGeburtsdatum);
                            doc.Add(tabelleNameGeburtsdatum);
                            // STAMMVEREIN - Name und Nummer in einer Zeile
                            verein stammverein = person.holeStammverein(personid, connectionString);
                            string nameStammverein = institution.gebeNameVonInstitutionAngepasstAnDtype(stammverein.verein_id, connectionString);
                            string nummerStammverein = verein.holeVereinsnummerMitVereinID(stammverein.verein_id, connectionString);
                            Paragraph labelStammvereinName = new Paragraph(nameStammverein).AddStyle(grossDünn);
                            Paragraph labelStammvereinNummer = new Paragraph(nummerStammverein).AddStyle(grossDünn);
                            labelStammvereinNummer.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
                            Table tabelleStammverein = new Table(new float[] { 3, 1 });
                            tabelleStammverein.SetWidth(ausweisbreite);
                            //tabelleStammverein.LockedWidth = true;
                            tabelleStammverein.SetMargin(0);
                            Cell zelleNameSV = new Cell();
                            // zelleNameSV.SetPaddingTop = Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(1);
                            zelleNameSV.SetPaddingLeft(8);
                            zelleNameSV.SetBorder(keinRahmen);
                            zelleNameSV.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                            zelleNameSV.Add(labelStammvereinName);
                            tabelleStammverein.AddCell(zelleNameSV);
                            Cell zelleNummerSV = new Cell();
                            zelleNummerSV.SetBorder(keinRahmen);
                            zelleNummerSV.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                            // zelleNummerSV.SetPaddingTop = Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(1);
                            zelleNummerSV.SetPaddingRight(8);
                            zelleNummerSV.Add(labelStammvereinNummer);
                            tabelleStammverein.AddCell(zelleNummerSV);
                            doc.Add(tabelleStammverein);
                            // Tabelle für Mitgliedsnummer, Barcode und Nested-Table für Disziplinen
                            Table tabelleBarcodeDisziplinen = new Table(new float[] { 1, 1 });
                            tabelleBarcodeDisziplinen.SetWidth(ausweisbreite);
                            //tabelleBarcodeDisziplinen.LockedWidth = true;
                            tabelleBarcodeDisziplinen.SetMargin(0);
                            // linke Spalte (DISZIPLINEN)
                            Cell zelleDisziplinen = new Cell();
                            zelleDisziplinen.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
                            zelleDisziplinen.SetBorder(keinRahmen);
                            zelleDisziplinen.SetPaddingLeft(8);
                            // zelleDisziplinen.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
                            // NESTED-Tabelle Disziplinen
                            // 3 Spalten
                            Table tableDisziplinen = new Table(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 });
                            tableDisziplinen.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100)).UseAllAvailableWidth();
                            // GÜLTIGE DISZIPLINEN HOLEN UND DRUCHLAUFEN
                            List<string> gültigeDisziplinen = disziplin.holeGueltigeDisziplinenFürAusweisZuEinerPerson(personid, connectionString);
                            // Zähler für anzahl verarbeiteter Spalten in der Tabelle um ggf. mit leeren Zellen auffüllen zu können

                            // NEU: Nur wenn auch Disziplinen vorhanden, SONST leer einfügen
                            if (gültigeDisziplinen.Count > 0)
                            {
                                int zählerSpalte = 1;
                                foreach (string disziplinVerein in gültigeDisziplinen)
                                {

                                    Cell zelle = new Cell();
                                    zelle.SetBorder(keinRahmen);
                                    zelle.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
                                    Paragraph inhalt = new Paragraph(disziplinVerein).AddStyle(klein); ;
                                    inhalt.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
                                    zelle.Add(inhalt);
                                    tableDisziplinen.AddCell(zelle);
                                    zählerSpalte++;
                                    // Wenn Spalte 3 erreicht den Spaltenzähler wieder auf 1 setzen
                                    if (zählerSpalte == 3)
                                    {
                                        zählerSpalte = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                                // leere Zelle zum Auffüllen wenn Anzahl != 3 der Spalten in Tabelle
                                Cell zelleLeer = new Cell();
                                zelleLeer.SetBorder(keinRahmen);
                                zelleLeer.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
                                Paragraph inhaltLeer = new Paragraph(" ").AddStyle(klein);
                                zelleLeer.Add(inhaltLeer);
                                // prüfen bei welcher Spalte die Befüllung gestoppt hat
                                if (zählerSpalte == 1)
                                {
                                    // zwei leere Zellen auffüllen
                                    tableDisziplinen.AddCell(zelleLeer);
                                    tableDisziplinen.AddCell(zelleLeer);
                                }
                                if (zählerSpalte == 2)
                                {
                                    // eine leere Zelle auffüllen
                                    tableDisziplinen.AddCell(zelleLeer);
                                }
                                zelleDisziplinen.Add(tableDisziplinen);
                                tabelleBarcodeDisziplinen.AddCell(zelleDisziplinen);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int zählerSpalte = 1;
                                Cell zelle = new Cell();
                                zelle.SetBorder(keinRahmen);
                                zelle.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
                                Paragraph inhalt = new Paragraph(" ").AddStyle(klein);
                                inhalt.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
                                zelle.Add(inhalt);
                                tableDisziplinen.AddCell(zelle);
                                // leere Zelle zum Auffüllen wenn Anzahl != 3 der Spalten in Tabelle
                                Cell zelleLeer = new Cell();
                                zelleLeer.SetBorder(keinRahmen);
                                zelleLeer.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
                                Paragraph inhaltLeer = new Paragraph(" ").AddStyle(klein);
                                zelleLeer.Add(inhaltLeer);
                                // prüfen bei welcher Spalte die Befüllung gestoppt hat
                                if (zählerSpalte == 1)
                                {
                                    // zwei leere Zellen auffüllen
                                    tableDisziplinen.AddCell(zelleLeer);
                                    tableDisziplinen.AddCell(zelleLeer);
                                }
                                if (zählerSpalte == 2)
                                {
                                    // eine leere Zelle auffüllen
                                    tableDisziplinen.AddCell(zelleLeer);
                                }
                                zelleDisziplinen.Add(tableDisziplinen);
                                tabelleBarcodeDisziplinen.AddCell(zelleDisziplinen);
                            }

                            // rechte Spalte (AUSWEISNUMMER, BARCODE)
                            Paragraph labelAusweisnummer = new Paragraph(ausweisnummer).AddStyle(grossFett);
                            labelAusweisnummer.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
                            Cell zelleBarcodeNummer = new Cell();
                            zelleBarcodeNummer.SetPaddingRight(8);
                            //zelleBarcodeNummer.SetPaddingTop = Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(5);
                            zelleBarcodeNummer.SetBorder(keinRahmen);
                            zelleBarcodeNummer.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                            zelleBarcodeNummer.Add(labelAusweisnummer);

                            // ÄNDERUNGEN GDI+ Fehler HIER:
                            // VORHER: iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(barcodeDateinameKomplett);
                            // iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(barcodeDateinameKomplett)));
                            iText.Layout.Element.Image img = bcImage;
                            if (bcImage != null)
                            {
                                bcImage = null;
                            }
                            // Barcode-Image etwas verkleinern
                            img.ScaleAbsolute(Convert.ToSingle(double.Parse(img.GetImageWidth().ToString()) * 0.85), Convert.ToSingle(double.Parse(img.GetImageHeight().ToString()) * 0.85));
                            img.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                            img.SetPaddingTop(3);
                            zelleBarcodeNummer.Add(img);
                            // GDI+
                            if (img != null)
                            {
                                img = null;
                            }
                            // Druckdatum
                            Paragraph labelDruckdatum = new Paragraph(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()).AddStyle(klein);
                            labelDruckdatum.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                            zelleBarcodeNummer.Add(labelDruckdatum);
                            tabelleBarcodeDisziplinen.AddCell(zelleBarcodeNummer);
                            doc.Add(tabelleBarcodeDisziplinen);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rückgabe = "FEHLER: " + ex.Message;
            mySQL.speichereFehlermeldung(druck_id, ex.Message, connectionString);
        }

        //mySQL.erzeugeSofortDownloadFürEineDatei("Ausweisdruck", "ausweise/" + pdfDateiname + ".pdf", mySession.Current.benutzer.benutzerID.ToString(), "Ausweisdruck");

        return rückgabe;
    }
```

In Itext5 I used

```
Document.NewPage();
```

for every ID-Card inside the Loop.

How can I realise that in iText7? PDF-File with multiple Pages, each with a Size of 5 * 8 centimetres.

Hope someone can give some Impulses. Thanks

Comment: If the problem indeed is only to find something in iText 7 corresponding to the iText 5 `Document.NewPage()`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40860358/1729265).

Comment: Yes I found that, but I used it in the wrong way. Thanky you.

Answer (score 0):

Added a counter and at the End of the loop checking if counter is smaller then count of job:

```
doc.Add(new AreaBreak(iText.Layout.Properties.AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
```